# Can someone explain the phrase "Fat model, skinny controller"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm learning Ruby on Rails. I noticed this phrase "**Fat model, skinny controller**". I'm not sure what that means. Does that mean I have to use more code in model and less code in controller? Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You understand correctly. Main reason for this recommendation is that you only need process request parameters and initialize model layer in controllers. Business logic need to be implemented in model layer. This allows you to avoid code duplication and made testing easier using unit tests for models.

Also read [this](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/7-move-model-logic-into-the-model) and go through whole site for best practices.

Answer (score 5):

In short yes you have the idiom right, although if any piece of code with a defined role becomes bloated it can be a problem and may need some basic re-factoring.

Business logic used in models can be re-used in multiple different routes, or in web-service APIs, or a command-line script. It can also be unit tested without invoking the web server.

The same business logic in the controller can only be used via the web interface.